# Network Interface starts without IPV4

Tags: networking, boot, ipv4, rhel-6

When I boot some RHEL 6.5 server, the NIC shows an IPV6 address but no IPV4 on `ifconfig`
However, if I `ifdown` + `ifup` it, it gets its IPV4 address (via DHCP).
For clarity, is is enabled on boot via `ifcfg-em1` `ONBOOT=yes`

What am I doing wrong to miss the IPV4 address on boot?

**Edit**

`/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-em1` content:

```
DEVICE=em1
HWADDR=90:B1:1C:71:46:77
TYPE=Ethernet
UUID=46136e95-f76b-4443-a63c-911466f8bd52
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=yes
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
```

`ifconfig` output after reboot

```
em1       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 90:B1:1C:71:46:77  
          inet6 addr: fe80::92b1:1cff:fe71:4677/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:14696 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:329 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1517399 (1.4 MiB)  TX bytes:44306 (43.2 KiB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:ef400000-ef420000
```

`ifconfig` output after `ifdown` / `ifup`

```
em1       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 90:B1:1C:71:46:77  
          inet addr:10.25.31.29  Bcast:10.25.31.255  Mask:255.255.254.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::92b1:1cff:fe71:4677/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:14696 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:329 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1517399 (1.4 MiB)  TX bytes:44306 (43.2 KiB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:ef400000-ef420000
```

**Edit 2**
I have renamed `em1` to `eth0` using [this guide](http://www.sysarchitects.com/em1_to_eth0). But it doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: What's your ip addr output? What's your network config look like?

Comment: Please see edits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to remove persisted rules, after making sure eth0 had caught and ipv4 address. Hence the sequence

```
ifup eth0
rm /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules
reboot
```

I am not sure what got persisted nor why, but it worked right away